# first try at understanding java generics

Tags: java

Below is a program that I have written in order to understand generics programming in Java.
As you would probably have noticed I am new to java and not surprisingly this program does not compile.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GenericBox<T>
{

    private List<T> t;
    private Iterator<T> itor;

    public GenericBox()
    {
            t = new ArrayList<T>();
            itor = t.listIterator();
    }

    public void insert(T t)
    {
            itor.add(t);
    }

    public T retrieve()
    {
            if(itor.hasNext())
            {
                    return itor.next();
            }

    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

            GenericBox <String> strbox = new GenericBox<String>();
            GenericBox <String> intbox = new GenericBox<String>();

            strbox.insert(new String("karthik"));
            strbox.insert(new String("kanchana"));
            strbox.insert(new String("aditya"));


            String s = strbox.retrieve();
            System.out.println(s);

            s = strbox.retrieve();
            System.out.println(s);

            s = strbox.retrieve();
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The compilation errors that I get are given below.

```
GenericBox.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        itor.add(t);    
            ^
  symbol:   method add(T)
  location: variable itor of type Iterator<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class GenericBox
1 error
```

Can someone point out what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a fix-my-typo request.

Comment: I don't think it's a typo, but lack of understanding of inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is not the generics. They are workable. Your error is in:

```
itor.add(t);
```

You don't add objects to an iterator.

You add them to the list. The iterator can only enumerate and iterate over them. Use

```
this.t.add(t);
```

I'd rename the list to `tList` and change the code to:

```
private List<T> tList;
private Iterator<T> itor;

public GenericBox()
{
        t = new ArrayList<T>();
        itor = tList.listIterator();
}
public void insert(T t)
{
        tList.add(t);
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

You have declared an object `itor` of type `Iterator<T>` and initialized it with an object of type `ListIterator<T>`.  Thus through the reference `itor` you can access only the methods of `Iterator<T>`.  If you want to access the `add()` method of `ListIterator` then `itor` must be declared as a `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator<T>` does not have an `add<T>(T)` method. You probably meant to call `this.t.add(t);` instead of `itor.add(t);`.